# Global variable used by recursive function

Tags: graph, global-variables, depth-first-search

Suppose you have to implement `Graph` class, containing some algorithms, using dfs (depth-first search). For instance, it might be connectivity check and `Graph` class would look like that:

```
class Graph {
    void dfsConnected(int v) {
        visited[v] = true;
        //indexing over v's adjacencies and calling dfsConnected recursively
    }
    bool isConnected {
        //indexing over vertice list and calling dfsConnected
    }
}
```

Suppose we have a bunch of algorithms, using dfs in this class (every of them uses specific dfs).
The problem is `visited` array:

- we could define it as a private field for every dfs like `visitedConnectivity`, `visitedTopSorting`, `visitedBridges`, etc. So we will have a lot of private variables in the every instance of `Graph`. And what if we have 3-4 such “global” variables for every dfs?
- we could pass `visited` as a `dfs`'s argument . In this case, we will have overhead on the every dfs call.

So, what is the easiest and real-world used solution for this problem? Of course, it is related not only to graph algorithms, but I found it easier to explain it in dfs terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more OOP way, in my opinion, is delcaring a field `visited` for each DFS class, and make it run its own DFS....

It will prevent you from keeping track 'what did I allocated? where is it connected to? etc..."

Your DFS will be much more capsulated, and will require fewer data, then adding an extra parameter for each dfs, which you will have to maintain separately.

The performance issue in here is neglected [in most cases] to the readability and [maintainability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability) you achieve with encapsulating as much data as possible in the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

pass on `visited` as an argument. There is no overhead!

Update OK I stand corrected. Let me say there is negligable overhead ;) Still, I'd choose keeping a pointer in the stack around over having a field/global variable that's meaningless outside the function and eating memory after it's done every day.

If you really care, you might encapsulate the DFS in an object which has its own `visited` field and takes the graph as an argument. But even then that probably translates to a function call with the object pointer on the stack.

Comment: why do you say there is no overhead? if visited is a `vector`, it will be copied - and there is overhead. If it is an array, this won't solve the problem, since it will only be passed by reference. Can you explain your logic for this answer?

Comment: I'm thinking of passing by reference. Why does that not solve the problem?

Comment: There is. On the every call a pointer to `visited` will be stored in the call stack.

Comment: I imagine any good compiler is going to optimize an unchanging value passed as a const ref and store it in a register. If in doubt, check the assembly output of your compiled function and see what it does. Also, *measure* before going to great lengths to pre-optimize.

Answer (score 0):

you could use static variables!

Comment: how would they help? can you elaborate?